# Keep the drawable smaller than the imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have a vector drawable image, that its size is `24dp`. I would like to show the image inside an `Imageview` that is larger but keep the drawable at the center at size `24dp`.
The following makes the drawable bigger:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/the_image_drawable"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageView` has some tricky param: [`ScaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType). by default it is set to [`FIT_CENTER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType#FIT_CENTER), so in fact [`Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit#CENTER). from doc:

> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also **ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly**. The result is centered inside dst.

try to exchange this attr to `CENTER` or `CENTER_INSIDE`, these aren't using scaling at all

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/the_image_drawable"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
```